# How to get the Form data validated by manager/admin before storing in database

Tags: html

i am try to create a application which requires Form filled data will be sent to manager/lead for validation before storing it in database. I had an idea about redirecting to manager login page when submitting form data, but i think its not feasible . is it possible any other way ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store it in the database, but add a column indicating manager approval.

Have everything (except the manager approval interface) ignore the row until that column is marked approved.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to store the information in the database before approval.  Then, add a column to the table called 'approved' that is initially set to 0.  When the manager approves it, set it to 1.

Comment: I was planning to store it in temporary database before approval, but your method gives much better utilization of resource..thanks :)